# How to hide tags in a specific position in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a custom built CMS and content looks fine in the WYSIWYG editor, but on the web site front end there are extra br tags that shouldn't be there, I'm wondering if I can hide them using CSS (there is a master.css file)

Here's an example of the problem - note the br tag at the end of each line

```html
 <div class="column threequarter">
                    <h3>I need to hide the break tag at the end of this line and the following line</em></strong>&nbsp;</p><br />
<p>&nbsp;</p><br />
<h4>I need to hide the break tag at the end of this line</h4><br />
<p>I also need to hide the break tag at the end of this line.</p><br />
```

Trouble is, I don't want to hide ALL br tags throughout the site but if I could just hide them within the  then that would probably suffice.

Comment: Did you try just using `br { display: none; }`?

Comment: I didn't. But wouldn't that apply to the whole site?

Comment: `.threequarter br { display: none; }` or introduce some other class or something to hide the br's

Comment: That worked. Many thanks!

Comment: ah, actually it didn't work - it affected the whole site, not just the class="column threequarter"  

It might be something to do with where I put it in the css file

Comment: Do you understand what I mean when I said to introduce a class? You need to use some class or ID or something in your CSS selector that represents the element that has br's that you want to hide. So like `<div class="post"><br></div><footer><div><br></div></footer>` - if you want to hide the br's in the `.post` div(s), you would do `.post br { display: none; }`. Or if you only wanted to hide them in the footer, use `footer { display: none; }`. If you just did `div br { display: none; }` or `br { display: none; }` it would hide the br's in both `.post` and `footer`

Comment: Thanks I worked it out. This is what I ended up doing

#content.layout75-25 .column.threequarter br{
display: none;
}

Answer (score 1):

As the HTML documentation in the link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp says, **The `<br/>` tag also supports the *Global Attributes in HTML*.** You just set a class for the required `<br/>`tag and then set `display:none;` for those particular elements. Here is an example,

HTML:

```
    <br class="mystyle" />
```

CSS:

```
    .mystyle{
        display:none;
    }
```

Comment: You could shorten your approach by adding a css class `hiddenBreaks` and be done with it or setting up the CSS style via Javascript or jQuery

Comment: please use a stack snippet whenever you can for questions and answers. :)